# bad zip file error while loading the trained deep learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I trained my model in colab and save it with torch.save('model.pth')
and then when i wanted to load it in my pycharm i get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Amin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1334, in         _RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`
```

can anyone help me to fix this error please
i could not find any solution for it on internet

i used tensorflow for training my model and used these imports :

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
```

my program can load the tokenizer that i have built but it wont load the model

this is my model :

```
max_features = 1000
maxlen = 650 
embedding_dims = 50 
filters = 250 
kernel_size = 3 
hidden_dims = 250

model5 = Sequential() 
model5.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_dims )) 
model5.add(Dropout(0.2))

model5.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1))

model5.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model5.add(Dense(hidden_dims)) model5.add(Dropout(0.2)) model5.add(Activation('relu'))

model5.add(Dense(5)) model5.add(Activation('softmax')) 

model5.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model5.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=14,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

torch.save(model5,'model.pth')
```

i loaded my model in colab and it was fine but it didn't work in pycharm

```
relative_model_path = "model.pth"
full_model_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_model_path)

model = torch.load(full_model_path)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\PycharmProjects\\src\\model\\categorizer.py", line 25, in \<module\>
model = torch.load(full_model_path)
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\serialization.py", line 789, in load
return \_load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, \*\*pickle_load_args)
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\serialization.py", line 1131, in \_load
result = unpickler.load()
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\saving\\pickle_utils.py", line 48, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
raise e
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\saving\\pickle_utils.py", line 46, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
model = saving_lib.load_model(filepath)
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\saving\\experimental\\saving_lib.py", line 196, in load_model
raise e
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\saving\\experimental\\saving_lib.py", line 173, in load_model
with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath, "r") as zipfile_to_load:
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\zipfile.py", line 1267, in __init__
self.\_RealGetContents()
File "C:\\Users\\Amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\zipfile.py", line 1334, in \_RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")`your text`
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: You are saving a Keras model with pytorch? That will not work.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy hi  can i use pickle.dump  or its only works with keras.model.save ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to save the model with

```
keras.save('model')
```

not torch because the model was built in tensorflow keras

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).